# Why Python 3 pickle cannot read Python 2 pickle data?

Tags: python, pickle

I have a Python 2 pickle file that when I try to read it with Python 3 it shows the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Here are some code sample in Python 2 and Python 3:

**python_2_dump.py**

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Python 2 version
import cPickle

test = {
  'Á': 'A',
  'á': 'a',
  'Ã': 'A',
  'ã': 'a',
  'Â': 'A',
  'â': 'a',
}

with open('test.pickle', 'w') as f:
  cPickle.dump(test, f)
```

**python_3_load.py**

```py
# Python 3 version
import pickle

with open('test.pickle', 'rb') as f:
  print(pickle.load(f))
```

Is there any reason Python 3 doesn't detect the old protocol and convert it accordingly? If it was the other way around, i.e. Python 2 reading a Python 3 pickle data, it makes sense.

Comment: Maybe a `unicode`/`bytes` problem. Seems like your keys are meant to be Python 3 `str`/ Python 2 `unicode`, so try `u'Á': 'A',` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protocol is detected automatically, as stated in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pickle.html#pickle.load):

> The protocol version of the pickle is detected automatically, so no
> protocol argument is needed.

However, you need to use `fix_imports`, `encoding` and `errors` to control compatibility support for pickle stream generated by Python 2. The [relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/pickle.html#pickle.Unpickler):

> The optional arguments `fix_imports`, `encoding` and `errors` are used to
> control compatibility support for pickle stream generated by Python 2.
> If `fix_imports` is true, pickle will try to map the old Python 2 names
> to the new names used in Python 3. The `encoding` and `errors` tell pickle
> how to decode 8-bit string instances pickled by Python 2; these
> default to ‘ASCII’ and ‘strict’, respectively. The encoding can be
> ‘bytes’ to read these 8-bit string instances as bytes objects. Using
> encoding='latin1' is required for unpickling NumPy arrays and
> instances of datetime, date and time pickled by Python 2.

In your example, it will read the `test.pickle` if you pass `encoding='utf-8'`:

`print(pickle.load(f, encoding='utf-8'))`

output:

```
{'Ã': 'A', 'â': 'a', 'Á': 'A', 'ã': 'a', 'Â': 'A', 'á': 'a'}
```